# create random array from a pool of int php

Tags: php, arrays, shuffle

here's what I trying to do:
 create an array of random 100 values from a list of 20-30 user IDs.
   I need to make the amount of each user equal as possible.  (if there are 25 users each would have 4 spots in the array, (100 / 25 = 4) and the order needs to be random.

as an example with an array of 10 and 3 user IDs:
    The array could read (3,2,3,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,1).
       here there are three 3's, three 2's and four 1's.
      which is as equal as possible while still filling the array of ten.

HELP ME PLEASE...

here is a mock up of how it will be deplployed 
http://fitzpicks.com/squarebet.php

In the mockup I'm using an string create by a spreadsheet to fill in the cells.

p.s. I'm just starting out with html,css and php so please don't make fun or break my site with your super hacking skills!

Cheers Greg

Comment: Are the user IDs sequential?

Comment: Just a note, this would fail as 'random', simply due to the predictability of the occurrence of id's.  It would be one thing to have a relatively uniform distribution of random numbers, but completely another to actually check and modify a 'random' selection like that... would this be used for some form of security?  That would be an important question to have answered first.

Comment: Nevermind, just checked your example... probably not a security thing, then... and random-looking would be random enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
$ids = array(1,2,3,4);
$count = 10;

// get number of full sets
$full_sets_number = floor($count/count($ids));

// number of ids in last not full set
$rest_ids_number = $count % count($ids);

// get random ids that will occur more frequently
$rest_ids = $ids;
shuffle($rest_ids);
$rest_ids = array_slice($rest_ids, 0, $rest_ids_number);

// fill result array with ids
$result_array = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $full_sets_number; $i++)
{
    $result_array = array_merge($result_array, $ids);
}
$result_array = array_merge($result_array, $rest_ids);

// shuffle it
shuffle($result_array);

var_dump($result_array);
```

Output for above code is something like this:

```
array(10) { [0]=> int(4) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> int(1) [3]=> int(1) [4]=> int(3) [5]=> int(1) [6]=> int(4) [7]=> int(4) [8]=> int(2) [9]=> int(3) }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem could be solved in this simple way: you need to repeat your IDs array up to desired count and then [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) it. There could be a 'tail' (if `total count`/`count of IDs` is not integer) - to make a better random, I suggest to retrieve random IDs from original array then. Here's a sample:

```
$rgIds  = [5, 72, 10, 93];
$iCount = 30;

$iLoop    = (int)($iCount/count($rgIds)); //count of repeats
$rgResult = array_intersect_key( //'tail' from random Ids
               $rgIds, 
               array_flip(array_rand($rgIds, $iCount%count($rgIds))));
for($i=0; $i<$iLoop; $i++)
{
   $rgResult=array_merge($rgResult, $rgIds);
}
shuffle($rgResult);
```

this sample will result with this test:

```
var_dump($rgResult, array_count_values($rgResult));
```

in following output:

```
array(30) {
  [0]=>
  int(93)
  [1]=>
  int(93)
  [2]=>
  int(5)
  [3]=>
  int(93)
  [4]=>
  int(10)
  [5]=>
  int(72)
  [6]=>
  int(10)
  [7]=>
  int(5)
  [8]=>
  int(72)
  [9]=>
  int(10)
  [10]=>
  int(5)
  [11]=>
  int(93)
  [12]=>
  int(72)
  [13]=>
  int(5)
  [14]=>
  int(72)
  [15]=>
  int(10)
  [16]=>
  int(5)
  [17]=>
  int(10)
  [18]=>
  int(93)
  [19]=>
  int(93)
  [20]=>
  int(93)
  [21]=>
  int(72)
  [22]=>
  int(5)
  [23]=>
  int(93)
  [24]=>
  int(72)
  [25]=>
  int(72)
  [26]=>
  int(10)
  [27]=>
  int(5)
  [28]=>
  int(10)
  [29]=>
  int(72)
}
array(4) {
  [93]=>
  int(8)
  [5]=>
  int(7)
  [10]=>
  int(7)
  [72]=>
  int(8)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example from the [PHP manual entry for shuffle](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php):

```
<?php
$numbers = range(1, 20);
shuffle($numbers);
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    echo "$number ";
}
?>
```

In your case, if you want to use values from an initial array four times, you could do something like this:

```
$ids = array(101, 102, 109, 110);
$random = array_merge($ids, $ids, $ids, $ids);
shuffle($random);
foreach ($random as $id) {
  echo "$id ";
}
```

I think you could then just work with the first 100 items in the `$random` array.

In future, you could take a look at all the [array functions in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) for an appropriate function.

Comment: I had posted a reply similar to this, but Gustav got it first, and his code is tighter.  This is the answer I believe you are looking for.